# Is there now a way to initialize a fixed size array of char using initializer lists in C++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

I have a class similar to this:

```
class A
{
    char _s[6];
public:
    A(const char s[6]) : _s{s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]}
    { }
};
```

Is this the only way to initialze `_s` using C++11 initializer-list for `char[]` (or any other basic type array)?

Comment: is variadic constructor an option for you?

Comment: @PiotrS. I don't think so, no.

Comment: Sometimes, not initializing in the ctor-init-list and doing it in the ctor-body instead is appropriate.

Comment: Is the missing `s[3]` intentional?

Comment: @T.C. no, it was not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A {
  std::array<char, 6> _s;

public:
  A(std::array<char, 6> s) : _s(s) {}
};

int main() {
  std::array<char, 6> s;
  A a{s};
}
```

Or if you want to avoid copying the array into the constructor:

```
class A {
  std::array<char, 6> _s;

public:
  A(std::array<char, 6> const &s) : _s(s) {}
};

int main() {
  std::array<char, 6> s;
  A a{s};
}
```

---

You should be aware that your constructor `A(const char s[6])` does not take an array, but a pointer. It's identical to `A(char const *s)`, so the constructor has no idea what the size of the array you pass in is. This is just one of those bizarre things about raw arrays and one of the many reasons not to use them.